Can I package a pretrained tensorflowjs model within my ReactJs App
I am looking to use tensorflowjs on the browser as part of my ReactJS app. The model I am trying to use (as a proof of concept) is toxicity model. It is meant to detect overly toxic reviews and prevent the form form being submitted.
The issue is when I load the model, it downloads the model over the network which takes quite awhile.
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadModel() {
      tfjs.setBackend('webgl');
      setIsModelLoading(true);

      const threshold = 0.6;
      const toxicityModel = await toxicityClassifier.load(threshold);

      setModel(toxicityModel);
      setIsModelLoading(false);
    }
    if (model === null) {
      loadModel();
    }
  }, [model]);

  const predictToxicity = async (value) => {
    const predictions = await model.classify([value]);
    console.log(predictions);
    setTextToxicity(
      predictions
        .filter((item) => item.results[0].match === true)
        .map((item) => item.label),
    );
  };

above is the useEffect hook for my code. the toxicityClassifier.load takes a good 10 seconds. That prevents my predictToxicity function to function correctly (model is still null as its not loaded).
On further investigation, i found that its because the model is downloaded over the network when the component first loads. Is there anyway i can package the model with the react code rather than have it consistently download over the network?
Another way is to start a worker in the background when the page first loads. This bring a bit of complexity for now and i would prefer not to do this.
